# UnityConfig.cs file while keeping unity.mvc5 with unity.webapi together in the same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Nuget package manager keeps only one UnityConfig.cs file so I need to merge both of them so that both packages work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Unity;

namespace project_name
{
    public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            // register all your components with the container here
            // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

            // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Unity.Mvc5.UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        }
    }
}
```